# Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length at JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

```
                $scope.loader.isSaving = true;
                var json = {
                    spread: $scope.spread.toJSON()
                };
                $scope.flatForm.jsonForm = JSON.stringify(json);
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(json).replace(/\"/g, "\\\""));
                $timeout.cancel(delay);
                delay = $timeout(function() {
                    SpreadSheetService.save($scope.spread);
                }, 300);
```

When I run the above code, I have got such error.

```
    Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length
        at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
        at Object.doneFunction (spreadSheetController.js:631)
        at HTMLButtonElement.g (sweet-alert.min.js:1)
    (anonymous) @ spreadSheetController.js:631
    g @ sweet-alert.min.js:1
```

How can I fix this error?
Please help me.

Comment: Change `spread: $scope.spread.toJSON()` to `spread: $scope.spread`

Comment: But it has same bug, though I change it.